# How to adress error message related to S4 object in R?

Tags: r, spatstat

I'm with spatstat package in R.I'm working on species distribution models mainly on point process models.

My goal is to **evaluate the predictive performance of point process models** of Gibbs, Log-Gaussian Cox, and many more, point processes.

I've fitted Gibbs models to my data and when doing prediction

```
predict(f.ppm, window = W, covariates=present$bio4)
```

an error occurs

> Error in covariates[covnames.needed] : objet de type 'S4' non indicable

which means that object of type 'S4' cannot be identified.

`present` yields:

```
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 694, 350, 242900, 5  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent     : 248674.5, 598674.5, 683042.6, 1377043  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names      :       bio4,       llds,       mimq,        pet,         SV 
min values :   10.02888,    4.00000,   95.45561, 1293.52945,    0.00000 
max values :   25.00000,    8.00000,  222.91389, 2062.00000,    7.80565
```

Comment: Can you please provide data? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I think your problem arises from `present$bio4`. What is the output of it?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your object `f.ppm` is a fitted model of class `ppm`. Then your code is invoking the `predict` method for this class, `predict.ppm`. The help file for `predict.ppm` states that the argument `covariates` should be "either a data frame, or a list of pixel images of class `im`". Your data `present$bio4` does not conform to either of these formats. You will need to convert the data to the required format.